# How to open Flutter app mobile view in desktop or laptop browser?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

How to run Flutter web(designed for mobile) in Desktop or Laptop browser as mobile view without inspect(becoz I don't want developer tools)

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YecGq.png)

Comment: it doesn't work that way you have to Use MediaQuery class to design ui for different different size .

Comment: Why do you need to have it in mobile view on desktop browsers? What is wrong with the display on bigger screens?

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh witout mediaquery is there any way in chrome setting

Comment: it run but app not responsive  use  command `flutter build web --release`  it generate web folder inside build folder

Comment: yes I know , when i run on pc browser design looks horrible, its comfort only when on inspect and mobile view

Comment: But when on mobile view there are devs tools also available I need to hide dev tools

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.